# How to create a dataframe from a nested list?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm new to R (and stackoverflow!) so please be kind if this is a bad question/badly described.

I am trying to fill a dataframe from a nested list. Currently I have a nested list of information about 50 petitions which I scraped from the web. I want to create a dataframe which has the number of signatures from each of 650 parliamentary constituencies, so that each column is a petition and each row is a constituency.

So at the moment I can call the number of signatures for a petition (the first [[1]]) and constituency (the second [[1]]):

```
> json[[1]][["data"]][["attributes"]][["signatures_by_constituency"]][[1]][["signature_count"]] 

[1] 1144
```

I also managed to make a dataframe from the constituency names...

```
for (i in 1:650){
constituencies[[i]] <- json[[1]][["data"]][["attributes"]][["signatures_by_constituency"]][[i]][["name"]]
}

constituencies <- data.frame(constituencies)

                                 constituencies
1                                     Aldershot
2                           Aldridge-Brownhills
3                      Altrincham and Sale West
4                                  Amber Valley
5                       Arundel and South Downs
6                                      Ashfield
7                                       Ashford
...
650                   Cardiff South and Penarth
```

Now I need to replicate this so each petition is a new column with the number of signatures for each constituency.

I tried:

```
 for (a in 1:50){
     signatures <- list()
     for (b in 1:650){
         signatures[[b]] <- json[[a]][["data"]][["attributes"]][["signatures_by_constituency"]][[b]][["signature_count"]]
     }
     cbind(constituencies, signatures)
 }
```

But I just got:

```
Error in json[[a]][["data"]][["attributes"]][["signatures_by_constituency"]][[b]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can initialize the `signatures` outside the `for` loop

```
signatures <- vector('list', 50)
for(a in 1:50){
    for(b in 1:650) {
        signatures[[a]][[b]] <-  json[[a]][["data"]][["attributes"]][["signatures_by_constituency"]][[b]][["signature_count"]]
    }
  }
```

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
signatures <- vector('list', 3)
for(a in 1:3){for(b in 1:2) {signatures[[a]][[b]] <- 1:5}}
```

Comment: @OwenWinter if there are errors, you can wrap with a `tryCatch` and return an NA for those cases that didn't have any element

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. Turns out one of my petitions only received signatures in 649 constituencies but I got around this with `for(b in 1:length(json[[a]][["data"]][["attributes"]][["signatures_by_constituency"]]))` and I'll go in manually for the petition with one wrong.